# Youtube api not found video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to find video "[Desposito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk)" on yuotube with API. It was published on January 13, 2017. The query string is as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2017-01-13T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&publishedBefore=2017-01-13T23%3A59%3A00.000Z&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

But the response doesn't include the video I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding `q=desposito` to your search parameters might help.  You might also have to adjust your time parameters to account for time zone differences; for example, 10pm on Jan 13 in Mexico City is outside your search window.  (And, to be picky, your current parameters exclude the last 59 seconds of the day.)

Comment: Even if I put - 2 days and + 2 days, the result is the same. What I'm saying is that the API doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The video you want isn't on the first page of results. Limit it with a search param.

This works fine:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=desposito&part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2017-01-13T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&publishedBefore=2017-01-13T23%3A59%3A00.000Z&key=[API_KEY]
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/RpayhI7uhEMSDFk9CHdtyV62vi0\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 356,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"tnVOtk4NeGU6nDncDTE5m9SmuHc/3g-rbj2UgHGdPTC1Nk7zLAWtTHU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "kJQP7kiw5Fk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-01-13T05:00:02.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCLp8RBhQHu9wSsq62j_Md6A",
    "title": "Luis Fonsi - Despacito ft. Daddy Yankee",
    "description": "Despacito” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/DOoUzFp “Imposible” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "LuisFonsiVEVO",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: It's not that I want to find this particular video. I want to get the most viewed video of the day. This video is " Desposito". But the API doesn't find it for any search parameters. I don't need to use the "q=desposito" parameter.
It would be logical to think that if we use the "order=viewCount" parameter, we will get it at number one in the response. But this does not happen.